# how to configure a different catalina.out log for each deployed WAR on tomcat

Tags: logging, tomcat

I've a tomcat 8.5 instance running with several WAR's deployed, each of them writing its internal output via `System.out` to console.

Now, tomcat combines all this log outputs together in one file: catalina.out, but I would like to separate them. Is it possible to configure tomcat's logging properties to create different catalina.outs on a per-WAR-base, e.g.

- console output of app1.war -> catalina-app1.out
- console output of app2.war -> catalina-app2.out

...

Thanx
Tom

Comment: better if you use tomcat virtualhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put "swallowOutput" in your context.xml

```
<Context swallowOutput="true">
...
</Context>
```

and add an individual logging.properties file into each of your webapps/wars at the position

```
/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties
```

You can put this file also in the source-folder if your WAR is generated, e.g. by eclipse

```
/src/logging.properties
```

The logging.properties may have the following contents

```
  handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = webapp_name.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.OneLineFormatter
```

and you can define the name prefix for each individual webapp log with `org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix`

Answer (score 0):

If you add for app1 and app2 in `WEB-INF/classes` file like `log4j.properties` and put inside something like:

```
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yyyy
log4j.appender.logfile.File=${catalina.base}/logs/app1.log
```

(change filename for second app)

you will have in files `app1.log` and `app2.log` the output of tomcat for particular app

Comment: I'm not using log4j but instead basic raw `System.out.println` for logging. Does your proposed config work also for this in order to divide the output into several files?

Comment: @tombo_189, have no idea, maybe will be better to ask in https://stackoverflow.com/